# characters ">>" in LaTeX

Tags: typewriter

I'm writing about programming language [Haskell](http://haskell.org) and I need to describe operators named `>>=` and `>>`. I wrap all references to names from the programming language in `\texttt{ ... }`, for example:

```
We use operator \texttt{+} to add two numbers.
```

But when I write `\texttt{>>}`:

```
We use operator \texttt{>>} to sequence two actions.
```

I got the "much greater than" sign, which is not what I want (see the image).

I found some questions asking similar problem ([“<<” sign in Latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134928/sign-in-latex)), but the solutions proposed there don't work for me:

[image: Various approaches and how are they rendered]

The only solution I found is to break `\texttt{>>}` to `\texttt{>}\texttt{>}`, but it gets painful when I use longer expressions; for example:

```
To sequence many actions, use \texttt{a1 >> a2 >> a3 >> ... >> a4}
```

must be broken to

```
To sequence many actions, use \texttt{a1 >}\texttt{> a2 >}\texttt{> a3 >}\texttt{> ... >}\texttt{> a4}
```

I'd rather avoid using `\verb`, because:

1. I want to be consistent with the rest of the text using `\texttt`
2. I sometimes need to use formatting in the code snippets to emphasize a variable or something

P.S.: I do use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: use package `listings` for the code sequences

Comment: Consider the `listings` package for automatic formatting of source code, or if you are on *nix, the `minted` package based on Python/Pygments for even superior syntax coloring.

Comment: I use `listings` for multi-line code listings, but didn't know about `\lstinline`. I'll have a closer look at `\lstMakeShortInline`, but it doesn't seem to work in `\item[...]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are ligatures. You can either avoid them locally by putting braces between the input. Or globally with microtype:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[>,<]{encoding = T1,family=tt*} %
\begin{document}
\texttt{>>}   %need the microtype command.
\texttt{>{}>} %works always
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this seems to work! I had to `\usepackage{lmodern}` because I was getting `pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable` ([answer on tex.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/pdftex-error-font-expansion-auto-expansion-is-only-possible-with-scalable)).

Comment: @honzasp: An alternative to lmodern is to install the cm-super-package.