# Cyrillic and microtype: pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts

Tags: pdftex, microtype, cyrillic

I have a rather huge document and everything worked fine. The problems started when I tried to insert some Russian text. I was able to resolve some issues, but now I'm stuck with the following error:

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.
```

It was really hard to produce a MWE, but it looks like it has something to do with `microtype` package. I don't fully understand what it does, but it's part of the template, so I'd like to keep it.

Here comes the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,factor=900]{microtype}

\newcommand{\ru}[1]{{\begin{otherlanguage*}{russian} #1 \end{otherlanguage*}}}

\begin{document}

Here is a Russian text:
\ru{Здравствуйте! Как у вас дела? Меня зовут Калеб. Как вас зовут?}

\end{document}
```

I've introduced the `\ru` command for convenience. However, it also produces the error without this command. But if somebody wants to suggest a good way of inserting text in a different language - feel free :).

**Edit 1**

Added `\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}`, added missing part of error message.

I'm using TeX Live from Ubuntu 12.10:
`pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)`

Comment: I don't get any such message. In any case, add `\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}` before loading `babel`. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: you can see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/pdftex-error-font-expansion-auto-expansion-is-only-possible-with-scalable, it might help

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. And now I'm totally confused. I didn't use `lmodern` in the MWE since it is used in the original template and still produces the error. However, the use of the package fixes the MWE. I'm a bit frustrated. Is it really so hard to write texts with Cyrillic letters? :(

Comment: OK, but the `cm-super` hint worked. I have installed the Ubuntu package. The document itself remained unchanged. And now it works! Why is this? I thought all the information is somehow in the tex-file?