# dtx file: how to run it?

Tags: errors, compiling, microtype, dtx, font-expansion

I want to clarify first that I am a beginner, and thus my question might be imprecise or inadequate. Anyway:

I found this documentation file for the package microtype, can be easily found on ctan. It is `microtype.pdf`. I like the format of the document and the font of the document, so I downloaded the `.dtx` file and try to see how they got it. Of course, I cannot understand almost anything about the code. Anyway I try to compile it with pdfLaTex. But this does not work, as a series of errors and warnings appear.

I report the last lines of the log file, if they are useful

```
[1{C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                              \fi \fi 
l.767 %\newpage

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on microtype.log.
texify: pdflatex.exe failed for some reason (see log file).
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Ususally the _first_ error is the important one (at least the first one should try to solve...)

Comment: See [pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10706)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`microtype.dtx` uses the EC fonts (=Computer Modern in T1 font encoding). You need to install the scalable Type 1 variants. They are available as `cm-super`. Install it with the package manager.

Comment: not really. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

First the answer to your initial question: the document uses Bitstream Charter as the main font, Bitstream Letter Gothic for the code, and (in the latest version) Adobe's Source Sans Pro for the sectioning. There are [several methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/7674) of finding out which fonts are used in a PDF document, even without looking at the source code. But if you do want to look at the code, you'll find that the fonts are set shortly after the exclamation "`Let's abolish CM!`"

The errors you get are probably caused by a missing font. Martin has already given you a link to the relevant question, I especially recommend [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10837/7674) for finding out which font is missing on your system. (Charter and Source Sans Pro are available on CTAN, for Bitstream Letter Gothic - which AFAIR is not – you could use URW Letter Gothic as a replacement, by changing the line `\def\ttdefault{blg}` into `\def\ttdefault{ulg}`.)

EDIT: Note that I am referring to the latest version (2.5a). In previous versions, the font switching commands were commented in the `dtx` file, so that compiling it at home would use the EC fonts (as @Heiko says), while the pre-compiled `pdf` still featured Charter and Letter Gothic.