# pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts even with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex

According to this question: [On pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts, microtype package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283960/on-pdftex-error-font-expansion-auto-expansion-is-only-possible-with-scalable), to get rid of the error, a scalable font must be loaded.

Package `lmodern` no longer seems available in `MikTeX`; all the "lm-something" package my repository offers are shown below:
[image]

Given that I install `cm-super` font family and add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to my document. But the error is still there.

MWE (excerpt from [overleaf user Craig's CV sample](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/curriculum-vitae/ztykfkztnqfh#.VztAi5ErI2w)):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{My}{Name}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{my address, line 1, line 2, line 3, postcode}{}{}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\makecvtitle

Undergraduate electrical and electronic engineer completing the final year of a master's degree. 

\end{document}
```

What do I do to make the error go away? Thanks. Your help is appreciated.

Update:
I followed the step Ulrike Fischer suggested in  [How do I invoke cm-super?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88368/how-do-i-invoke-cm-super). Now it seems `cm-super` is not correctly installed (I see a `.pk` rather than a `.pfb` in the log) even though I do have it in MikTek Package Manager [image]

I have refreshed FNDB and updated formats in `MikTek Options (Admin)` after installing `cm-super`.

Googling leads me to [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11086&f=48) , but I don't know how to follow the advice. Could someone please tell me how to execute M.A. solution "updating pdftex.map by running initexmf --mkmaps" in Windows MikTek 2.9? And what else have I missed?

Comment: I get no error when I run your document in texlive2016

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am willing to give up on MikTek and install TexLive at this point but ctan.org is down. Ctan mirrors are still running, but the search facility of all mirrors I have tried is based on the main ctan.org and is down. I have no way to find a usable download address of TexLive now. I will try again and see if ctan.org gets back online. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I didn't particularly mean you should install Tl (the results in miktex should be the same) but just mentioned which version i had used, for completeness. (ctan is planned downtime, it'll be back tomorrow morning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure but I think package `lmodern` should be part of the basic installation of MiKTeX.

Please see the following image. I called the MiKTeX Package manager and filtered for `lm` (Latin Modern).  Then you can see if Latin Modern is installed, if you see an date in column `Installed on`.  BTW: Do not forget to call package `lmodern` to activate Latin Modern in your TeX document ...

[image: MiKTeX Package Manager Latin Modern]

On the other side you should be able to install it later with the MiKTeX package manager, like you tried with `cm-super`.

Now to the last sentences of your question:

In windows you can open the terminal/console with:

`Windows-key+R`, type `cmd`, press `enter` and type the mentioned command into the new window: `initexmf --mkmaps`, then press `enter` ...

Comment: (+1) Apologies for confusing things. People post too quick - I can't keep up!

Answer (score 2):

I will answer this question of my own for documentation purpose: `MikTeX` by default doesn't come with any scalable fonts that `pdfTeX` is happy with - who knows exactly what makes `pdfTeX` happy except `cm-super`... When using `MikTeX`, if encounter `auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts` error, install `cm-super` fonts family, execute `initexmf --mkmaps` command in console, and add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to TeX document.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't come with scalable fonts? Isn't it just that Computer Modern isn't available in scalable form? The standard postscript set are surely included, aren't they? I thought they were part of even the most basic LaTeX install.

Comment: @cfr Rephrased.