# What is the Windows MikTeX equivalent to "updating pdftex.map by running initexmf --mkmaps"?

Tags: miktex, windows

I have been having this problem: [pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts even with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310120/pdftex-error-font-expansion-auto-expansion-is-only-possible-with-scalable-fon)

My most recent trouble-shooting step is what Ulrike Fischer suggested in  [How do I invoke cm-super?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88368/how-do-i-invoke-cm-super). Now it seems `cm-super` is not correctly installed on my PC (I see a `.pk` rather than a `.pfb` in the log) even though I do have it in MikTeX Package Manager [image]

I have refreshed FNDB and updated formats in `MikTeX Options (Admin)` after installing `cm-super`.

Googling leads me to [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11086&f=48) , but I don't know how to follow the advice. Could someone please tell me how to execute M.A. solution "updating pdftex.map by running initexmf --mkmaps" in Windows MikTeX 2.9?

And what else do you think I may have missed?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Usually I simply run `updmap --verbose`  from the command line (the switch is just to see what happens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows you can open the terminal/console with:

`Windows-key+R`, type `cmd`, press `enter` and type the mentioned command into the new window: `initexmf --mkmaps`, then press `enter` ...

Comment: Do you think it would make sense to answer the original question, which has more information? I voted to close this just before you answered. When I initially suggested answering, I didn't realise it was a duplicate. Very sorry.

Comment: @cfr When I realized `cm-super` was not even properly installed I felt it became a new problem, so I started this question. Very sorry if  this is recognized as a duplicate.

Comment: @Alex But you also updated that question with the new information, so that seems to reflect this question as well. It is often difficult to say where one question ends and the next begins. I am not necessarily correct by any means!