# Change tracking for sans serif font

Tags: sans-serif, letterspacing

I want to change the tracking (space between the characters) for a sans serif font. I found that I can use the microtype package to change the tracking of the smallcaps font (`\textsc{foo}`), but I can't figure out how to make `\textsc{}` a sans serif font.

Comment: did you try `\textsf`?

Comment: I don't know how to make the tracking package modify testsf instead of testsc...  Hm. Let me try...

Comment: No, it didn't work

Comment: you can only make textsc into a sans serif font if you _have_ a sans serif small caps font (most font sets do not) microtype will apply if you have such a font.

Comment: Well, my goal remains — I want to change the tracking between the characters in a sans serif font. I don't know how to do this. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: you spelled it with an "s" in your comment: `\testsf`.  that should be "x": `\textsf`.  (but the result wouldn't be small caps in any event; most sans fonts don't have matching small caps.)

Comment: Oh, that's cause I made a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean, you want to 'set tracking' only for your sans serif font? (Because I hope you don't want to 'make' small caps be sans serif ... rather you should choose a sans serif that contains a small caps schape, as in the below example.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{my}
  { encoding = *,
    font = */sf*/*/*/*,
}
\SetTracking[
%  spacing = {500*,166, }
]{
  encoding = *,
  family = sf*,
}{ 500 }
\SetTracking[]{encoding = *, family = rm* }{ 10 }
\SetTracking[]{encoding = *, shape = sc }{ 100 }

\def\test{I want to change the tracking (space between the characters)
  for a sans serif font. I found that I can use the microtype package
  to change the tracking of the smallcaps font
  ({\ttfamily\textbackslash textsc\{foo\}}), but I can't figure out
  how to make {\ttfamily\textbackslash textsc{}} a sans serif font.}

\begin{document}
\parskip 12pt
\parindent 0pt

RM:

\test

SF:

{\sffamily\test}

SC (RM):

{\scshape\test}

SF+SC:

{\sffamily\scshape\test}

TT:

{\ttfamily\test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried compiling that and got this error: `! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
fonts.`

Comment: By Tracking, I mean that I want the text to look like this:  T H E `  `  T E X T

Comment: I know what you want to achieve. I choose a deliberately exaggerated value for your sans serif family. But I don't know why you get that `pdfTeX` error. (I am using TeX Live 2016: ` pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)`; `libertine.sty    2014/11/25`; `microtype.sty    2016/05/14`.) If you are using MikTeX, then maybe this question is of value: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283960/8528 ..?

Comment: okay. apparently Macports corrupted my LaTeX installation (again???) and I had to wipe it and download TeXLive. Now it works great. Thanks!

Comment: @vy32 -- Glad it works!