# microtype producing dozens of Unknown slot number warnings

Tags: microtype

With TeX Live 2017, `microtype` has started producing dozens of
unknown slot number warnings. This does not happen with TeX Live
2016 (fully updated). Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

This produces dozens of warnings, starting with these two:

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\`A'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/358(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\'A'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/358(protrusion)'.
```

The list goes all the way to z, and might include every accented character. I get the same error with `Cardo`,`Gentium Plus`, and `Times New Roman` (all the fonts I tested).

This seems to be a bug.

Comment: I can confirm this, unfortunately

Comment: I had this problem, too, but it is gone now. Does microtype have a public repository and a bug tracker, e.g. on github? I could not find it and it is not mentione on the CTAN page https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype

Comment: I have the same error message with texlive2021, after an update a month ago!!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is due to a change in how latex declares legacy (LICR) input for unicode characters (the warnings only crop up with `TU` encoding, i.e., with xelatex or lualatex, and only for `microtype` settings that contain LICR input – in your case, the default settings).

**EDIT:** This issue has been fixed with version 2.7 of `microtype`.

---

Solution for older versions of the `microtype` package:

```
\makeatletter
\def\MT@is@composite#1#2\relax{%
  \ifx\\#2\\\else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\MT@char\expandafter{\csname\expandafter
                    \string\csname\MT@encoding\endcsname
                    \MT@detokenize@n{#1}-\MT@detokenize@n{#2}\endcsname}%
    % 3 lines added:
    \ifx\UnicodeEncodingName\@undefined\else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MT@is@uni@comp\MT@char\iffontchar\else\fi\relax
    \fi
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MT@is@letter\MT@char\relax\relax
    \ifnum\MT@char@ < \z@
      \ifMT@xunicode
        \edef\MT@char{\MT@exp@two@c\MT@strip@prefix\meaning\MT@char>\relax}%
          \expandafter\MT@exp@two@c\expandafter\MT@is@charx\expandafter
            \MT@char\MT@charxstring\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
% new:
\def\MT@is@uni@comp#1\iffontchar#2\else#3\fi\relax{%
  \ifx\\#2\\\else\edef\MT@char{\iffontchar#2\fi}\fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Please let us know here when the package is updated.

Comment: There seems to be another issue, I'm getting `pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable fonts.` with texlive 2017 in file that compiled with texlive 2016 and the fonts MyriadPro. I just don't have the time to build a MWE.

Comment: @KeksDose This means that you are using a non-Type 1 font. See here, e.g.: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/pdftex-error-font-expansion-auto-expansion-is-only-possible-with-scalable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10706/7674), especially Ulrike's answer

Comment: @Robert File works with texlive 2016 or if I comment out the microtype package with texlive 2017. I'll investigate asap.

Comment: @Robert There is an issue with my /texmf-local tree, I've been asking this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374154/4736

Comment: @Robert OK, was a stupid question and no connection to microtype. I forgot to enable the map files of my local tree!

Comment: @Robert I have microtype 2.7a but still get the errors - the microtype package seems to have something that looks like your fix. I use LuaLaTeX

Comment: For reference I am using the Bergamo Std font.

Comment: As @Jean-MichaëlCelerier said, the answer does not prevent the errors in all cases with version 2.7a where the workaround is no help neither. For compatibility issues with `siunitx`, you need to load the package `textcomp`.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier The Bergamo Std font does not contain the glyphs for which you get the warnings, so it's not a result of this previous bug, but indeed expected behaviour. For the fix I would refer you to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380897/7674).

Comment: @strpeter See my comment ^^^^.

Comment: I have the same error message with texlive2021, after an update a month ago!!!

Comment: @tatojo (1) it's not an error but a warning. (2) which font are you using? (3) did you check the answer I linked to two comments above yours?

Comment: @Robert, I don't get pdf, before the texlive update everything was ok. Using TeXGyre Pagella. Yes, I tried your sggestion, didn't help. I think they modify somehow `microtype`, but can't find what! Some long and complex files stopped to compile!!! Sad!

Comment: @tatojo well, if your document doesn't compile anymore, then that's a different issue. I suggest you ask a new question including a minimal example and the error message you get. BTW, microtype was last updated in March.