# texlive 2017: local fonts not found

Tags: fonts, texlive-2017, texmf-local

texlive 2017 on Linux. Commercial fonts are installed in /texmf-local . Under texlive 2017 the local fonts files are not found, while they are found under texlive 2015 on the same machine. Both installations use the same /texmf-local tree.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[pagesize, ngerman, fontsize=12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel, blindtext}

\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument{}

\end{document}
```

If I compile this MWE with texlive 2015, the logfile ends with these lines:

```
{/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/e
nc/dvips/MinionPro/base-MinionPro-aa.enc}{/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/
enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}{/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/enc/dvips/
MinionPro/base-MinionPro-ab.enc}</local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/M
inionPro/MinionPro-Bold.pfb></local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/Minio
nPro/MinionPro-Regular.pfb></local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/c
m-super/sfsx1200.pfb></local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-supe
r/sfsx1440.pfb></local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfsx
1728.pfb>
Output written on MinionPro-test-tl-2015.pdf (4 pages, 119264 bytes).
PDF statistics: ...
```

But texlive 2017 can't find the fonts:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file MinionPro-Bold-Base-aa): Font MinionPro-Bold-Base
-aa at 655 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

But the kpathsea knows, where to find the file:

```
 kpsewhich base-MinionPro-aa.enc
/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro/base-MinionPro-aa.enc
```

Maybe I made a mistake during installation of texlive 2017: I agreed to make symbolic links. If this might be the cause of the error, can I correct that without reinstalling texlive?

There are no other TeX installations on the machine.

Comment: "at 655" means normally that pdftex was trying to make a bitmap. So the map entry is missing. Did you enable the map files?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Öhh, no? Do I have to? In which file is stored, which map files are enabled? If I knew this, I could have a look into the texlive 2015 installation and see, which files were enabled in which way. You may remember that I had some rare fonst, e.g. Palatinosans, which only work with pdftex.

Comment: Search for updmap.cfg in web2c-folders. Or try `updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPro.map`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right, I haven't made a new install of texlive since some years. After I »enabled« the map files, all is well. Would you drop two or three lines, which I could accept as an answer? -- And thank you for your timely help.

Comment: TL 2017 finds mine even though I told it it must not try to make symbolic links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"at 655" means normally that pdftex was trying to make a bitmap. So the map entry is missing.  Try `updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPro.map`.