# Why does my .otf font not like microtype's protrusion?

Tags: microtype, protrusion

And, more importantly, what can I do to fix it? No MWE, since it happens every time I use a particular font (and not when I don't or disable `microtype`'s protrusion). These are the warnings I get:

```
... hyph-de-1996.tex: Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character(microtype) `\k A'(microtype) in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list(microtype) `microtype.cfg/390(protrusion)'.
... hyph-de-1996.tex: Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character(microtype) `\u A'(microtype) in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list(microtype) `microtype.cfg/390(protrusion)'.
```

And so on, repeated many times. I am using `LuaLaTeX`. The font is proprietary, and I own the full .otf version. Anything I can do, or ask when bringing it up with the vendor?

Comment: As always: you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a minimal self contained example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Didn't I just explain why I did not provide one? It only happens with that one font (Equity by Matthew Butterick, by the way) which people are unlikely to have access to. I really only need help with understanding the error message, as it were. So this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373594/microtype-producing-dozens-of-unknown-slot-number-warnings/373607 seems also unrelated.

Comment: what happens if you use `\k A` with the font?

Comment: Further search found this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380812/microtype-warning-unknown-slot-number-of-character-with-lato-font Looks promising, going to check it out.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The font does not have the `Ą` or `Ă` characters, but then I don't use them anywhere in the document, either.

Comment: See it is also important to know exactly how you setup the fonts for the document, just to rule out basic user errors. Hence why we always ask for it

Comment: well that is the reason and you will have to adapt the list, and as I see you already found the answer which tells you how to do it. You could also try to add an fallback, it would be interesting to know if microtype accept this.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the pointing me in the right direction. The answer I found explains the underlying issue.