# Microtype: 'Unknown slot number of character' for Palatino in classicthesis w/ LuaLatex

Tags: luatex, microtype, cleanthesis

I'm trying to convert my document to use `classicthesis`. By default, it uses the `palatino` font, which however results in the following error at while compiling with LuaLatex:

```
File: mt-Palatino.cfg 2012/03/10 v1.0 microtype config. file: Palatino and simi
lar fonts (LBD)
)

Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `Ḃ (= \.B)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-Palatino.cfg/109(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `Ḡ (= \=G)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-Palatino.cfg/109(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `Ǩ (= \v K)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-Palatino.cfg/109(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `Ȳ (= \=Y)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-Palatino.cfg/109(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `ḃ (= \.b)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-Palatino.cfg/109(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `ﬀ (= ff)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU'.
(microtype)                Make sure it's a single character
(microtype)                (or a number) in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-Palatino.cfg/109(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `ḡ (= \=g)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-Palatino.cfg/109(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `ǩ (= \v k)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-Palatino.cfg/109(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `ȳ (= \=y)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-Palatino.cfg/109(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `ﬆ (= st)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU'.
(microtype)                Make sure it's a single character
(microtype)                (or a number) in protrusion list
(microtype)                `palatino-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `ﬅ (= st)'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU'.
(microtype)                Make sure it's a single character
(microtype)                (or a number) in protrusion list
(microtype)                `palatino-default'.

Package microtype Info: Character `‥' is missing
(microtype)             in font `TU/TeXGyrePagella(0)/m/n/10.95'.
(microtype)             Ignoring protrusion settings for this character.
Package microtype Info: Character `‼' is missing
(microtype)             in font `TU/TeXGyrePagella(0)/m/n/10.95'.
(microtype)             Ignoring protrusion settings for this character.
Package microtype Info: Character `⁰' is missing
(microtype)             in font `TU/TeXGyrePagella(0)/m/n/10.95'.
(microtype)             Ignoring protrusion settings for this character.
! Undefined control sequence.
¹...ain_tl {1}\cs_set_eq:NN \__um_sub_or_super:n 
                                                  \sp \tl_set:Nn \l__um_tmpa...
l.27 \begin{document}
                   
? X


Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 68440 strings out of 478531
 100000,3417909 words of node,token memory allocated 1379 words of node memory still in use:
   22 hlist, 1 vlist, 10 rule, 1 dir, 3 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 62 attribute, 116
 glue_spec, 58 attribute_list, 5 if_stack, 3 write, 16 pdf_literal, 1 pdf_dest, 
17 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:15,3:1,4:7,5:6,6:3,7:33,8:4,9:4,11:3
 86004 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 73 fonts using 24591727 bytes
 111i,1n,134p,10600b,2237s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
! error:  (pdf backend): already written content discarded, no output file produ
ced.
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This seems to be related to prior posts such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373594/microtype-producing-dozens-of-unknown-slot-number-warnings) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380812/microtype-warning-unknown-slot-number-of-character-with-lato-font). However, I have an up-to-date MacTex installation (i.e. `microtype` > 2.7) and double checked that the characters warned about are actually defined in the inheritance list `mt-Palatino.cfg`, as suggested by the second post.

EDIT:
The reason for the compilation error seems to be an incompatibility of `microtype` and/or `unicode-math` with `luainputenc`.

MWE (or non-working for that matter):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\usepackage{microtype} 
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
MWE
\end{document}
```

This code only compiles if I set `protrusion=false`, or disable either `unicode-math` or `luainputenc`.

Comment: Make a small complete example that can be used for a test. If possible one that doesn't load classicthesis, which is a rather large package.

Comment: Is your microtype version up-to-date? I have  microtype 2021/03/14 v2.8c.

Comment: Providing a MWE seems challenging in this case. The basic `classicthesis` example compiles without an issue. Moreover, my document seems to compile with Palatino enabled, if I manually disable `microtypes` character protrusion feature in `classicthesis.sty`. 

Yes, I also have  microtype 2.8c installed, and in fact made sure yesterday by updating to MacTex 2021.

Comment: well if a basic example compiles but only your document fails, then your document contains something we can't know and  a MWE is vital.

Comment: The main problem appears to be the undefined command `\__um_sub_or_super:n`, rather than the warnings. I was the original author of `mt-palatino.cfg` a decade ago. As I recall, it didn’t cause any problems back then to use the same protrusion list for Palatino and its clones that had fewer glyphs, but a newer version of `fontspec` started trying to fix missing glyphs. It would be difficult to do anything about this, because different versions of the same font cover different ranges.

Comment: While we're waiting for a MWE (or at least the full log), just a hint that the error is from the `unicode-math` package.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the additional hints. I could figure out that there is an incompatibility with `microtype`/`unicode-math` and the `luainputenc` package I previously loaded because of another issue. I now reverted to `inputenc` and that seems to fix it for now.

Comment: The error can be fixed by adding `\expandafter\let\csname __um_sub_or_super:n\endcsname\relax`. However, warnings will still occur -- that's just one unavoidable downside of using `luainputenc`. In fact, you should load neither `luainputenc` nor `inputenc` when compiling with luatex, unless you have very good reasons.

Comment: This has been fixed in `microtype` v3.0.