# Unknown character microtype.cfg/397(protrusion)

Tags: fonts, xetex, microtype

My book in Ukrainian. I use font Kraskario. By compilation, get long list of error

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\'s'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/397(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\c s'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/397(protrusion)'.


...

Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\v Z'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/397(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\'z'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/397(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\.z'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/397(protrusion)'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\v z'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/397(protrusion)'.
```

If font was changed on Piazzolla error message was disappears.

What is the problem? Visually, the PDF looks pretty good (I mean Kraskario font), and I don't see anything to indicate the lack of characters.

At example, I made so

```
\documentclass[twoside, 14pt, openright]{extreport}
\usepackage[a5paper, outer=15mm,inner=12mm,top=20mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=1em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
% \usepackage[a5paper, outer=36mm,inner=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=28mm,footskip=1.5em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\def\sectiontitlename{РОЗДІЛ}
\def\parttitlename{Частина}

\author{Ігор Юхименко}
% =============================================================================
%
%                           НАЛАШТОВУЄМО ШРИФТИ
%
% =============================================================================
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{Kraskario}{TU-basic}

\setstretch {0.85}
\setsansfont{Attractive}    % Sans font
% \setmainfont{Marmelad}
\setmainfont{Kraskario}         

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\DeclareCharacterInheritance
   { encoding = {TU,EU1,EU2},
     family   = {Kraskario} }
   { A = {\`A,\'A,\^A,\~A,\"A,\r A,\k A},
     a = {\`a,\'a,\^a,\~a,\"a,\r a,\k a},
     C = {\'C,\c C},
     c = {\'c,\c c},
     D = {\DH},
     d = {\dj},
     E = {\`E,\'E,\^E,\"E,\k E},
     e = {\`e,\'e,\^e,\"e,\k e},
     I = {\`I,\'I,\^I,\"I},
     i = {\`i,\'i,\^i,\"i,\i},
     L = {\L},
     l = {\l},
     N = {\'N,\~N},
     n = {\'n,\~n},
     O = {\O,\`O,\'O,\^O,\~O,\"O},
     o = {\o,\`o,\'o,\^o,\~o,\"o},
     S = {\'S,\v S},
     s = {\'s,\v s},
     U = {\`U,\'U,\^U,\"U},
     u = {\`u,\'u,\^u,\"u},
     Y = {\'Y,\"Y},
     y = {\'y,\"y},
     Z = {\'Z,\.Z,\v Z},
     z = {\'z,\.z,\v z}
   }

\begin{document}

\counterwithin*{footnote}{part}
\newcommand{\speek}{—\enspace}

\input{Rain.tex}

\end{document}
```

Now I get a next error
`` (microtype)                `n-t.tex/57(protrusion)'. ``

Instead `` `microtype.cfg/397(protrusion)' ``.is  `` `n-t.tex/57(protrusion)'. ``

Comment: Does `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{Kraskario}{TU-basic}` help? See the Hints and caveats section in the documentation, or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380897/7674)

Comment: @Robert, Don't help. Maybe, problem in  \usepackage[final]{microtype}

Comment: hm, works for me with that line added, so you should provide a minimal example

Comment: @Robert, I was changed the description

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? By the way, you get a warning, not an error.

Comment: just delete the `\DeclareCharacterInheritance` block, which undoes the effect of the Alias declaration.

Comment: @Robert, I was deleted. It doesn't help. 
(./mt-Kraskario.cfg) - line from log.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman, I use xelatex. I know that is a warning. But I don't use extended Latin, only Ukrainian language.

Comment: where does `mt-Kraskario.cfg` come from? did you create it yourself, and what does it contain?

Comment: @Robert, I created it itself https://paste.centos.org/view/875f2660

Comment: why? it declares the inheritance settings for the Lato font, which you're not even using. could you post the complete log file?

Comment: oh, and maybe you also need the line `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{Attractive}{TU-basic}` for the sans font

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140398/discussion-between-igor-yukhimenko-and-robert).

Comment: turns out the OP had an outdated tex system, which was why the suggestion in my first comment didn't work. I suggest to close as duplicate.