# unknown slot number of character

Tags: xetex

I noticed multiple warnings about: *unknown slot number of character* when I compile my document with XeLaTex.

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `\v z'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `microtype.cfg/411(protrusion)'.
```

The character shown is slightly different in various warnings. I have no idea what does it mean.

Context: Overleaf, XeLaTex, TeX Live version: 2022

[Similar Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373594/microtype-producing-dozens-of-unknown-slot-number-warnings)

Comment: you don't say which font you're using, but I suspect adding `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{your font}{TU-basic}` would help. See the Hints and Caveats section in microtype.pdf, p.28.

Comment: It works very well. I'm using `Noto Sans CJK TC`, therefore I added `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{Noto Sans CJK TC}{TU-basic}`. The warnings are gone!