# Problem encountered when centering optimization problem formulation

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, align

I have tried centering the integer programming formulation using `\centering`, `\begin{center}` around the `\begin{align}` environment, but the formulation still appears to be flushed left. How can I go about aligning it to the center of the slide?

The following is the part of my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red!65!black, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=darkred}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=darkred}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithout{equation}{chapter} % remove the chapter number
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\title[Presentation Title]{Test}

% A subtitle is optional and this may be deleted
\subtitle{An Introduction}

\author{abc}



\date{PUT DATE HERE}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
  % You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
\end{frame}

% Section and subsections will appear in the presentation overview
% and table of contents.
\section{First Main Section}

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{frame}{First Slide Title}{Optional Subtitle}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item {
    My first point.
  }
  \item {
    My second point.
  }
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Second Subsection}

\begin{frame}[shrink]{The Integer Programming Formulation}
\begin{align}
&\min \quad 
\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T}} \sum_{(i,j)\in A} d_{ij} x_{tij}\\
\text{s.t.}\quad
\sum_{o\in O} b_o z_{ot} &\leq B\alpha_t \quad && \forall t \in \mathcal{T}\\
\sum_{t\in \mathcal{T}} z_{ot} &= 1 \quad && \forall o\in O\\
\sum_{(i,j)\in \delta^+(i)} x_{tij} &\geq z_{ot} \quad && \forall o \in O, t\in \mathcal{T}, i:l(i)\in L_o\\
\sum_{(i,j)\in \delta^+(i)} x_{tij} &= \sum_{(i,j)\in \delta^-(i)} x_{tji} \quad && \forall i\in V, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
\sum_{(s,j)\in \delta^+(s)} x_{tsj} &= \sum_{(j,s)\in \delta^-(s)} x_{tjs} = \alpha_t \quad && \forall t\in \mathcal{T}\\
x_{tij} &\leq \alpha_t \quad && \forall (i,j)\in A, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
z_{ot} &\leq \alpha_t \quad && \forall o\in , t\in \mathcal{T}\label{8}\\
\sum_{o\in O} z_{ot} &\geq \alpha_t \quad && t\in \mathcal{T}\\
\sum_{(i,j)\in \delta^+(i)} x_{tij} &= g_{ti} \quad && \forall i\in V, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
y_{ti} &\geq x_{tij} \quad && \forall (i,j)\in A, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
\sum_{j\in W} g_{tj} &\geq y_{ti} + \sum_{(j,k)\in A(W)} x_{tjk} \quad && \forall i \in W, W \subseteq V \setminus \{s\},|W|>1, t\in\mathcal{T}\\
x_{tij} &\in \mathbb{B} \quad && \forall (i,j)\in A, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
z_{ot} &\in \mathbb{B} \quad && \forall o\in O, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
0 \leq \alpha_t &\leq 1 \quad && t\in\mathcal{T}\\
y_{ti} &\leq \alpha_t \quad && \forall i\in V, t\in \mathcal{T}
\end{align}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And here's how it looks like after compilation:

[image: Formulation appears flushed left]

Comment: Not related: Are you sure presenting *this frame* to your audience is a good idea during the talk?

Comment: Don't use shrink, use a smaller font size instead.

Comment: @RuixiZhang No I am not. I copied over the original code from my main paper to see how it will look like on beamer. Thanks though!

Comment: It appears that there is an implicit `twocolumn` (or equivalence) issued somewhere. Please post your complete code, not just this fragment.

Comment: @RuixiZhang No, the problem is that shrink also shrinks the textwidth.

Comment: I have added in the rest of the code. @samcarter what will be a right way to go about using a smaller font for that frame?

Comment: Just issue a font changing command right after you started the frame: `\begin{frame}{The Integer Programming Formulation} \small` or `... \footnotesize`. I would not recommend going down to `\scriptsize` or `\tiny`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the beamer user guide:

> Never use a smaller font size to “fit more on a frame.” Never ever use the evil option `shrink`.

To fit all your content on one slide, not even `\tiny` is small enough. I would not recommend it, but with the following font size you can squeeze it on one frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red!65!black, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=darkred}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=darkred}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithout{equation}{chapter} % remove the chapter number
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\title[Presentation Title]{Test}

% A subtitle is optional and this may be deleted
\subtitle{An Introduction}

\author{abc}

\date{PUT DATE HERE}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The Integer Programming Formulation}
\centering
\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
\begin{align}
&\min \quad 
\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T}} \sum_{(i,j)\in A} d_{ij} x_{tij}\\
\text{s.t.}\quad
\sum_{o\in O} b_o z_{ot} &\leq B\alpha_t \quad && \forall t \in \mathcal{T}\\
\sum_{t\in \mathcal{T}} z_{ot} &= 1 \quad && \forall o\in O\\
\sum_{(i,j)\in \delta^+(i)} x_{tij} &\geq z_{ot} \quad && \forall o \in O, t\in \mathcal{T}, i:l(i)\in L_o\\
\sum_{(i,j)\in \delta^+(i)} x_{tij} &= \sum_{(i,j)\in \delta^-(i)} x_{tji} \quad && \forall i\in V, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
\sum_{(s,j)\in \delta^+(s)} x_{tsj} &= \sum_{(j,s)\in \delta^-(s)} x_{tjs} = \alpha_t \quad && \forall t\in \mathcal{T}\\
x_{tij} &\leq \alpha_t \quad && \forall (i,j)\in A, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
z_{ot} &\leq \alpha_t \quad && \forall o\in , t\in \mathcal{T}\label{8}\\
\sum_{o\in O} z_{ot} &\geq \alpha_t \quad && t\in \mathcal{T}\\
\sum_{(i,j)\in \delta^+(i)} x_{tij} &= g_{ti} \quad && \forall i\in V, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
y_{ti} &\geq x_{tij} \quad && \forall (i,j)\in A, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
\sum_{j\in W} g_{tj} &\geq y_{ti} + \sum_{(j,k)\in A(W)} x_{tjk} \quad && \forall i \in W, W \subseteq V \setminus \{s\},|W|>1, t\in\mathcal{T}\\
x_{tij} &\in \mathbb{B} \quad && \forall (i,j)\in A, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
z_{ot} &\in \mathbb{B} \quad && \forall o\in O, t\in \mathcal{T}\\
0 \leq \alpha_t &\leq 1 \quad && t\in\mathcal{T}\\
y_{ti} &\leq \alpha_t \quad && \forall i\in V, t\in \mathcal{T}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works, but after I add `\RequirePackage{microtype}` and 
`\microtypesetup{expansion=false}` as removing `\usepackage{lmodern}` somehow leads to a compilation error on my end..

Comment: @Stoner Works fine for me. Which tex distribution do you use?

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX

Comment: @Stoner With up to date package versions? What is your beamer version?

Comment: @Stoner And please show the error message you get

Comment: This is the error:
`! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...@Org@Shipout \box \@cclv 
                                                  
l.142 \end{frame}
                 
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on "Introductory Talk - Khoong Wei Hao.log".

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.`

Comment: and yes it is up to date, which I find it strange to have such an error..

Comment: @Stoner Maybe try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392467/36296

Comment: @Stoner Another approach would be to keep `lmodern` and use the `fixcmex` package to solve the scaling problems of this font.

Comment: Yes the font now looks consistent with the inclusion of the `fixcmex` package! Thanks a lot @samcarter! https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392467/36296 seems to solve the problem as well :)